# Qt application can't find QtGui4.dll and QtCore4.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, dll

This Qt application was complied by VS 2010 for the end users, but the executing application doesn't find Qt's dll. In the folder, there are QtGui4.dll and QtCore4.dll How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Well, in fact, it seems to find the DLL, but not the specific function within the DLL that it needs. Could you double check it's actually loading the correct DLL and does not pick up a Qt DLL from another application. Just put your EXE in Dependency Walker and see what paths to you DLLs is comes up with.

Comment: @Bart I think you are right. May be he put dlls of different Qt verion.

Comment: FYI, Dependency Walker can be found [at this link](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Dump your exe in there and see what it tells you. You might explicitly have to turn on the visualization of paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Dll Hell!

Everytime you use Qt for deployment you have to be sure that

1) The libraries against which you are compiling are the same version and the same compiler
2) There are no conflicts with other libraries in system path
3) If you compile Debug you must use *d.dll version of the libraries

Be sure for example that if your program is compiled with VC9 then also you dll are compiled with VC9.

You can understand which libraries you are linking against with a very useful program called Dependency Walker. http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Thank you linello. As you told me, the problem was because it's not the same compiler.

Comment: You're welcome. Always remember to work with same version of libraries and compilers, otherwise this kind of problems are very frequent.

Answer (score 0):

This is your app is compiled with a different version than the dlls.
Does it work if you run it from VS?